# Partitioning tables after creation using Crate

Tags: partitioning, crate

I was wondering if it's possible to do partitioning after table creation.

I'm trying to import ~2 million entries in a table (cluster), and if I partition the table before adding entries I get memory exceptions.

Comment: maybe your import creates a lot of partitions. what is your partition value?

Comment: maybe your configured heap is to low. whats your configured heap on each instance? You can find out in the admin-ui or by issueing: `select id, name, (mem['free'] + mem['used'])/1024/1024 as configured_heap_mb, mem['free']/1024/1024 as free_heap_mb from sys.nodes;`

Comment: Hi,this actually initial testing in migrating an postgres installation to Crate. It's typical a timeseries type so I've made a partition by day (~2 years collections) so I guess number of partitions gets high.

Comment: yeah, you'll get a lot of partitions, but more importantly a lot of shards!

`2 * 365 * num_shards`

so if you have your partitioned table with 4 shards, you will get 2920 shards in total. try to partition by month, or at least by week to minimize the number of partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to partition a table after its creation.

2M records is not a lot of data, but if you have problems importing data into a partitioned table (e.g. if you have a lot of partitions), you could import data per partition:

```
COPY table_name PARTITION (partition_column=column_name) WITH (option=value);
```

See [COPY FROM](https://crate.io/docs/stable/sql/reference/copy_from.html#copy-from).